# Problems with loading data from subdomains

Tags: magento-1.9, configuration, cdn

After rebuilding my Magento I realised that there is a few missing things like **css(missing icons, characters)** and some **jQuery/Javascripts** don't work.

After a little bit of a research I found that (everything works fine on dev site)
it is related to the **cdn** configuration:

> unsecure server => http://cdn1.xxx.xxx/js, http://cdn2.xxx.xxx/css ...
>   and so on.

everything works fine as a secure (almost) but have some problems with unsecure content.
Is it really better to have it like that or if I change everything to **www.xxx.xxx/js, ...css** etc will it be much slower ?